# Использование разных DLL при разных вариантах сборки

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

Есть две версии DLL - для х32 и х64. Называются они одинаково.

Как их прицепить к проекту, что бы в зависимости от конфигурации сборки бралась нужная версия DLL? Переименовать DLL нельзя.

Comment: Какая версия VS?

Comment: VS Express 2013 Desktop

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно вручную отредактировать .csproj и добавить `Condition` :

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Project.Reference.MyProject" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
        <HintPath>..\References\"Project.Reference.MyProject.40.x86.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Project.Reference.MyProject" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
        <HintPath>..\References\"Project.Reference.MyProject.40.x64.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Конечно же вместе условия `Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"` нужно будет адаптировать, взависимости в каком режиме вы компилируете.

В `<HintPath>` можете вводить относительный путь к вашей сборке DLL.

Вместо `$(Configuration)` вам скорее всего пригодится что-то вроде: `'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'`

[Документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/7szfhaft.aspx)